# Join calendar table to historical data

Tags: sql, join

I have a specific problem that I don't know how to go around. I have two tables:

companies_with_owners

```
|Company_ID|Priority|Owner|Created_at|Current_date|Archived|Updated_At|
|----------|--------|-----|----------|------------|--------|----------|
|123       |Good    |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |25.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|
|123       |Good    |Jane |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |12.11.2023|
|456       |Good    |Ben  |17.11.2023|27.11.2023  |TRUE    |21.11.2023|
|456       |Good    |Ben  |17.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |18.11.2023|
|789       |Bad     |Jane |01.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |17.11.2023|
...
```

date_dim table

```
|DATE      |
|----------|
|2013-11-16|
|2013-11-17|
|2013-11-18|
|2013-11-19|
|2013-11-20|
|2013-11-21|
...
```

As you can see my table with companies have duplicate records for the specific ID's when the change on the record happened. I want to receive a joined table for records that will be exploded by day for the companies from created at date to current date if archived = FALSE/ if archived = TRUE then I want those companies to be exploded by day from created at date to latest updated at date.

I wrote this query with inner join, but it duplicates the records for the company ID's. Is there any way I could write it so the dates are joined to the company ID's without duplication

```
with exploded_dates AS (
    SELECT 
        c.company_ID,
        d.date,
        c.owner,
        c.created_at,
        c.archived,
        c.updated_at,
        c.current_date
    FROM
        companies_with_owners c
    INNER JOIN
        date_dim d
    WHERE
        (
            c.archived = FALSE
            AND (d.Date BETWEEN date(c.created_at) AND date(c.current_date))
        )
        OR (
            c.archived = TRUE
            AND (d.Date BETWEEN date(c.created_at) AND date(c.updated_at))
        )
)

SELECT * from exploded_dates
```

Would appreciate the help

tried to inner join the table, cross join, was thinking about getting rid of the duplicated later by window function, but maybe it could be done with a proper join

my expected result for company 123 would look like this:

```
|Company_ID|Priority|Owner|Created_at|Current_date|Archived|Updated_at|Date      |
|----------|--------|-----|----------|------------|--------|----------|----------|
|123       |Good    |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |25.11.2023|27.11.2023|
|123       |Good    |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |25.11.2023|26.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |25.11.2023|25.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|24.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|23.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|22.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|21.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|20.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|19.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|18.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|17.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|16.11.2023|
|123       |Bad     |Ben  |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |15.11.2023|15.11.2023|
|123       |Good    |Jane |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |12.11.2023|14.11.2023|
|123       |Good    |Jane |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |12.11.2023|13.11.2023|
|123       |Good    |Jane |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |12.11.2023|12.11.2023|
|123       |Good    |Jane |11.11.2023|27.11.2023  |FALSE   |12.11.2023|11.11.2023|
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hello! I added the expected result for company 123 as an example. I need it to be exploded by day but without duplicates. Company 123 was changed 3 times in this period of time so I need the rows to be duplicated from last updated at date to the next one

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? It will be great if you can share the create schema sql and insert sample records sql for us to test the query before posting.

```
select Company_ID,
    case when date<=Updated_At then Priority else LEAD(Priority) over (partition by company_id and order by Updated_At) as Priority,
    case when date<=Updated_At then Owner else LEAD(Owner) over (partition by company_id and order by Updated_At) as Owner,
    Created_at,Current_date,
    case when date<=Updated_At then Archived else LEAD(Archived) over (partition by company_id and order by Updated_At) as Archived,
    case when date<=Updated_At then Updated_At else LEAD(Updated_At) over (partition by company_id and order by Updated_At) as Updated_At
    from companies_with_owners  cross join date_dim 
    where DATE  between created_at and CURRENT_DATE
    and case when Archived=True then date <=Updated_At else date <=CURRENT_DATE end;
```